# Android - Heap usage at Application Start and CG_CONCURRENT

Tags: android, garbage-collection, heap-memory

**I'm having troubles with performances on my application because of the GC, and I don't have really much experience to understand what's going on.** Here's the detailed situation of what's happening.

I'm trying to build an application that processes audio in real time by applying STFT ([quick explanation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2757/inverse-short-time-fourier-transform-algorithm-described-in-words/2758#2758)).

Basically, I take each buffer (in my case, the min buffer size is 1148 bytes), I apply a windowing function and I obtain a matrix of frames; then on each frame I apply the FFT; finally, I can apply to each frame some Gain based on the frequency and on the moment in time. Then I do the path back in order to obtain the modified version of the buffer.

Since my sampling frequency is 8000Hz, I have for each buffer to do the processing in less than 1148/8000 = 144ms. Using `System.currentTimeMillis()` I evaluated that each buffer processing takes usually between 70 and 100 ms, so that's fine.

But the problem comes from the Garbage Collector: my memory seems full, as you can see from the screenshot below; and the GC action makes my audio crack sometimes.

[image: Log of my application]

The problem is that I've noticed two things:

- If I don't do FFT and IFFT, but I simply leave the frame as it is, the CG_CONCURRENT message doesn't display. That's because FFT produces a lot of data (arrays of complex numbers)
- All the operations are done in a separate thread; so I've tried to cause manually a CG from the DDMS perspective just after the application has been launched. As you can see from the code below, in the onCreate method the application only loads the layout.. But when I cause a CG, I see that my heap is already more than 90% used ! I've looked at the heap dump and generated the Leaks Suspect report, and the most of the memory is occupied by the class 'android.content.res.Resources' and 'android.graphics.Bitmap'.. (here's the screenshots)

[image: Heap usage after application start]

[image: Leaks report piechart]

**So, do you have suggestions ? I think that's strange that my memory is already 90% used at the beginning.. And also that my heap can not increase a bit in order to satisfy my needs**

## Code

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.fileoutjava;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static final int BUFFER_FACTOR = 1; 

    DataInputStream dis;
    static final int FREQ = 8000;
    static final int FRAME_LENGHT = 32;
    static final int FRAME_SHIFT = 16;
    boolean isMusicStopped = true;
    AudioTrack at;
    Thread playThread;
    long time;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    public void playMusic(View v) {
        if (at == null) {
            Log.d("PLAY MUSIC", "LAUNCHING NEW PLAYER");
            playThread = new Thread(musicPlayerThread);
            playThread.start();
        }    
    }

    public void stopMusic(View v) {
        isMusicStopped = true;
        playThread = null;
    }


    Runnable musicPlayerThread = new Runnable() {       
        public void run() {
            Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

            /* eg: 8000 bytes per second, 1000 bytes = 125 ms */

            InputStream is = null;
            DataInputStream dis = null;

            try {
                is = MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("test.wav");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (is!=null)
                dis = new DataInputStream(is); //dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is,bSize));

            isMusicStopped = false;

            int min_bSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(FREQ, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
            int bSize = min_bSize*BUFFER_FACTOR;

            STFT stft = new STFT(FRAME_SHIFT,FRAME_LENGHT,FREQ,bSize);

            at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, FREQ, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);            
            at.play();

            int count = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bSize];

            time = System.currentTimeMillis();

            try {
                while (!isMusicStopped && (count = dis.read(buffer, 0, bSize)) >= 0) {


                    Log.d("TIME ELAPSED", ""+(System.currentTimeMillis()-time));
                    time = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    //Windowing
                    stft.frameBuffer(buffer);

                    //fourier transform and inverse
                    stft.fourierAnalysis();

                    // Overlapp-Add
                    stft.buildBuffer(buffer);

                    at.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }

                if (at != null) {
                    at.stop();
                    at.flush();
                    at.release();
                    at = null;
                }

                if (dis != null) {
                    dis.close();
                    dis = null;
                }

                if (is != null) {
                    is.close();
                    is = null;
                }

                if (stft != null) stft = null;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };


    private void stop() {
        isMusicStopped = true;
        playThread = null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        this.stop();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        this.stop();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

STFT.java

```
package com.example.fileoutjava;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

import android.util.Log;

import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.analysis.FFT;

public class STFT {

    private int fs, fl; //frame shift and frame length in ms
    private int n_fs, n_fl; //frame shift and length in samples
    private int buf_len; //length of the buffer array (bytes)
    private int data_len; //length of the buffer array (converted to short)
    private int padded_data_len; //put 0 padding before and after the buffer short[] data
    private float n_segs; //number of frames that can be taken from one buffer array
    private float[][] stft_matrix;
    private float[] window; //Hamming coefficient
    private float norm_factor = 0;
    private boolean search_norm_factor = true;
    private FFT fft;
    private int i,j,k; //index for loops
    private ByteBuffer bb;
    private float[] tmp_buf;
    private float[] tmp_fft;
    private float[] tmp_ifft;

    public STFT(int frame_shift, int frame_length, int freq, int buf_len) {
        fs = frame_shift;
        fl = frame_length;
        this.buf_len = buf_len;
        this.data_len = buf_len/2;      

        //compute values from ms to samples
        n_fs = (int) Math.floor(fs*freq/1000);
        n_fl = (int) Math.floor(fl*freq/1000);

        padded_data_len = 2*n_fl + data_len;

        //create coefficients
        window = hamming(n_fl);

        tmp_buf = new float[padded_data_len];
        bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(2);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

        //compute how many frames can be extracted from the buffer
        n_segs = 1 + (float) (Math.ceil((this.padded_data_len-n_fl)/n_fs));

        //data matrix: size of frame (with padding from previous frame) * number of segments
        stft_matrix = new float[n_fl][(int)n_segs];

        Log.d("STFT STATS", "BufLen:"+this.buf_len+" // Flen:"+n_fl+" // FSh:"+n_fs+
                " // Nsegs:"+n_segs);

        //Initialize the FFT object
        fft = new FFT(n_fl*2,freq);

        //buffers for FFT data, with zero padding
        tmp_fft= new float[n_fl*2];
        tmp_ifft = new float[n_fl];

        for (int i=0; i<n_fl*2; i++) {
            tmp_fft[i] = 0;
            tmp_ifft[i/2] = 0;
        }


    }

    //frames the whole buffer into the stft matrix
    public void frameBuffer(byte[] buf) {

        //initialize tmp_buffer and add 0 padding
        for (k=0; k<padded_data_len; k++)
            tmp_buf[k] = 0;

        //fill the short[] buffer converting from byte[] buffer

        for (i=0; i<buf_len; i+=2) {
            bb.position(0);
            bb.put(buf[i]);
            bb.put(buf[i+1]);
            tmp_buf[n_fl+i/2] = (float) bb.getShort(0);
        }


        //frame the short[] buffer into the matrix using windowing
        for (j=0; j<n_segs; j++) {
            for (int i=0; i<n_fl; i++) {
                stft_matrix[i][j] = tmp_buf[j*n_fs+i]*window[i];

                //NORMALIZATION FACTOR RETRIEVAL: only the first time
                if (search_norm_factor && (j*n_fs+i) == 512)
                    norm_factor+=window[i];
            }
        }

        if (search_norm_factor)
            norm_factor *= 1.2;
        //retrieve the norm factor only the first time
        search_norm_factor = false;

    }

    //sums all frames from STFT matrix into one buffer
    public void buildBuffer(byte[] output) {

        //initialize tmp_buffer and add 0 padding
        for (k=0; k<padded_data_len; k++)
            tmp_buf[k] = 0;

        //Overlap-Add
        for (j=0; j<n_segs; j++) {
            for (i=0; i<n_fl; i++) {
                tmp_buf[j*n_fs+i] += stft_matrix[i][j];
            }
        }

        //convert from short[] to byte[] (with normalization)
        for (i=0; i<buf_len; i+=2) {
            bb.position(0);
            bb.putShort( (short) (tmp_buf[n_fl+i/2]/norm_factor) );
            output[i] = bb.get(0);
            output[i+1] = bb.get(1);
        }

    }

    //FFT and IFFT of the buffer
    public void fourierAnalysis() {

        for (j=0; j<n_segs;j++) {

            for (i=0; i<n_fl; i++) {
                tmp_fft[i] = stft_matrix[i][j];
            }

            fft.forward(tmp_fft);
            //OPERATIONS ON THE SPECTRUM ?
            fft.inverse(tmp_ifft);


            for (int i=0; i<n_fl; i++) {
                stft_matrix[i][j] = tmp_ifft[i];
            }
        }   
    }


    //utility method for Hamming coefficients
    private float[] hamming(int len){
        float[] win = new float[len];
        for (i=0; i<len; i++){
            win[i] = (float) (0.54-0.46*Math.cos((2*Math.PI*i)/(len-1)));
        }

        return win;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The beginning of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10679174/987358 explains it: Heap increases as necessary and at app start there isn't needed much more.

Comment: Ok, but then why, when I start to compute the STFT (and in particular the FFT bock) the heap doesn't increase so that the CG_CONCURRENT can happen less frequently ?