# ViewPager, PagerAdapter and Bitmap cause memory leak (OutOfMemoryError)

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, android-viewpager, android-imageview

I have build a Android application which display weather data (I can give you the app name in private if you want to test the problem). The user can browse from one day to other to see weather of a specific day.

### App Architecture

My application uses fragments (single MainActivity with Navigation Drawer which calls specific fragments).

`DayPagerFragment` uses a `ViewPager` with an unlimited number of pages (dynamic fragments). A page represent a day.

**DayPagerFragment**

```
public class DayPagerFragment extends Fragment {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_day, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new DayAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    }

    private static class DayAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public DayAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return DayFragment.newInstance(null);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // I don't know the number to put here becauseI don't have 
            // a defined number of fragments (= dynamic fragments)
            return 1; 
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object){
            return DayAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
        }

    }

    public void setCurrentPagerItemPrev() {
        //mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        mAdapterViewPager.getRegisteredFragment(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }

    public void setCurrentPagerItemNext() {
        //mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
        mAdapterViewPager.getRegisteredFragment(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
    }

}
```

First optimisation: it is managed using a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` because `FragmentPagerAdapter` is not suitable for my use / dynamic fragments (stores the whole Fragments in memory).

Second optmisation: I have set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page with `setOffscreenPageLimit(1)`.

**DayFragment**

```
public class DayFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView mDay;
    private TextView mMonth;
    private Button mPrevDay;
    private Button mNextDay;
    private ImageView mCenter;
    private ImageView mLeft;
    private ImageView mRight;
    ...
    private DayRepository dayRepository;
    private Day currentDay;
    private Day prevDay;
    private Day nextDay;
    private DayUtil dayUtil;
    private DayUtil dayUtilPrev;
    private DayUtil dayUtilNext;
    private Calendar cal;
    private Calendar calPrev;
    private Calendar calNext;

    public static DayFragment newInstance(Calendar calendar) {
        DayFragment dayFragment = new DayFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("year", calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        args.putInt("month", calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        args.putInt("day", calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        dayFragment.setArguments(args);

        return dayFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_day_nested, container, false);

        mDay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_day);
        mMonth = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_month);
        mCenter = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_center); // Weather symbol (sun, cloud...) of D-Day
        mLeft = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_left); // Weather symbol of D-1
        mRight = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_right);  // Weather symbol of D-2

        //... get 6 others TextView/ImageView

        MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        // Get bundle args
        int day = getArguments().getInt("day");
        int month = getArguments().getInt("month");
        int year = getArguments().getInt("year");

        // Date
        this.cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);

        // Get prev/next day (for nav arrows)
        this.calPrev = (GregorianCalendar) this.cal.clone();
        this.calPrev.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
        this.calNext = (GregorianCalendar) this.cal.clone();
        this.calNext.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);

        // Get data from database
        //...

        // Utils
        this.dayUtil = new DayUtil(currentDay, getActivity());
        this.dayUtilPrev = new DayUtil(this.prevDay, getActivity());
        this.dayUtilNext = new DayUtil(this.nextDay, getActivity());
        String dateCurrentDayName = FormatUtil.getDayName(app.getLocale()).format(this.cal.getTime());
        String dateCurrentDayNameCap = dateCurrentDayName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + dateCurrentDayName.substring(1);
        String dateCurrentMonthName = FormatUtil.getMonthName(month, app.getLocale());

        // Update UI
        //... lot of setText(...) using day object and utils
        mLeft.setImageResource(this.dayUtilPrev.getDrawable());
        mCenter.setImageResource(dayUtil.getDrawable());
        mRight.setImageResource(this.dayUtilNext.getDrawable());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // Custom fonts
        MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getActivity().getApplication();
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
        ViewUtil.setTypeFace(app.getTrebuchet(), vg);

        // Navigation between days
        mMoonPrevDay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).viewDay(calPrev);
            }
        });
        mMoonNextDay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).viewDay(calNext);
            }
        });
    }

    // Never called!
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.w("com.example", "Fragment day destroyed");
    }

}
```

### The problem:

My application is very graphical because each page displays:

- 10 TextBox (inner text changes depending on the day)
- 4 ImageView (the weather symbol of D-1, D-Day, D+1) + another ImageView

I get OutOfMemoryError rapidly (after +/- 30 pages) when I browse the ViewPager pages.

It is like the Fragments are not being released from memory. The garbage collector does not work like I expected (I think it is because something references the old fragments).

**Logcat**

```
04-06 20:01:21.683  27008-27008/com.example D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 348K, 2% free 194444K/196608K, paused 93ms, total 93ms
04-06 20:01:21.683  27008-27008/com.example E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 1790260-byte allocation.
04-06 20:01:21.693  27008-27008/com.example E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example, PID: 27008
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
            at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:638)
            at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:367)
            at com.example.ui.DayFragment.onCreateView(DayFragment.java:126) //...mLeft.setImageResource()
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-06 20:01:21.773  27008-27008/com.example I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 197.480MB to 192.000MB
04-06 20:01:21.773  27008-27008/com.example D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 565K, 2% free 193932K/196608K, paused 73ms, total 73ms
```

I have memory leak but I don't know why and where.
I have used Eclipse MAT (Memory Analyser) but I don't know where to look.

Can you help me?

---

**Edit:** for load Typeface, I use the following code:

**DayFragment.java**

```
// Custom fonts
MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getActivity().getApplication();
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
ViewUtil.setTypeFace(app.getTrebuchet(), vg);
```

**MyApplication.java**

```
public Typeface getTrebuchet() {
    if (trebuchet == null){
        trebuchet = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), Consts.PATH_TYPEFACE_TREBUCHET);
    }
    return trebuchet;
}
```

My DDMS show the memory leak:

[image]

---

**Edit 2: IMPORTANT!**

I use a navigation drawer in my application which is handled by my only activity `MainActivity`. The navigation drawer uses fragments (and not activities).

This is why `DayPagerFragment` extends from a `Fragment` (and not from a `FragmentActivity` or an `Activity`).

To swipe between days, the user must touch two buttons (prev/next). I use `setOnClickListener` on these button in `DayFragment` (see my updated code).

The problem is that I call `((MainActivity)getActivity()).viewDay(calPrev);`

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        // Set up the navigation drawer
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }
    ...
    public void viewDay(Calendar calendar) {
        DayFragment dayFragment = DayFragment.newInstance(calendar); // The problem is here I think !
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
                .replace(R.id.container, dayFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }

}
```

So... I think that because I instanciate each time a new fragment, the `ViewPager` cannot do his job! And the `MainActivity` keeps a reference on each Fragments: this is why the garbage collector don't free the memory.

Now:

1. I don't know if my theory is correct
2. How to correct that? How, from `setOnClickListener` call `setCurrentPagerItemPrev` and `setCurrentPagerItemNext` methods (see my updated code in `DayPagerFragment`)?

NB : I use `mAdapterViewPager.getRegisteredFragment()` instead of `mViewPager.setCurrentItem` because my `DayAdapter` extends from `SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter`, but it is the same.

Comment: I am unable to find a solution to my problem. Nobody can help me / has a idea?

Comment: Try using library like http://square.github.io/picasso/ for maintaining the Image memory handling.

Comment: Have you finally solved your problem and can share how you did it?

Comment: Unfortunately no. This is why I have removed the ViewPager and I have implemented manually gesture controls to remplace the bahavior of the ViewPager. Not perfect but...

Answer (score 4):

You need to check 2 things here: images and typefaces.

Images uses loads of memory so you need to do some work to release them quickly. I've used the following code to help cleaning my memory, it removes references helping to clean up faster.

Also, loading many high quality images in a short amount of time might cause errors as Android is a bit slow to grow the heap space. See my answer to: [Android Understanding Heap Sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677850/android-understanding-heap-sizes/14462026#14462026). You might need to set *android:largeHeap="true"* in your manifest file, but only do it after optimising images and fonts.

Use the DDMS Heap view to check if you memory is maintaing a level, meaning you are cleaning up scrolled pages. This requires Android tools plugin to be installed on your IDE.

```
public abstract class SimplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
// ...
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
    unbindDrawables((View) object);
    object = null;
}
protected void unbindDrawables(View view) {
    if (view.getBackground() != null) {
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
    }
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
        }
        ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
    }
}
}
```

Then, check the way you get your fonts. Make sure you cache all calls to *Typeface.createFromAsset(...)*, like the example below:

```
public Typeface getFont(String font, Context context) {
    Typeface typeface = fontMap.get(font);
    if (typeface == null) {
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/" + font);
        fontMap.put(font, typeface);
    }
    return typeface;
}
```

---

### Edit: extra info after question was updated

Change your adapter to use a list of objects:

Return the size of that list on getCount(),

When adding objects to the list call:

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
mPagerContainer.invalidate();
```

Then, when you are getting closer to the end of the current list, request more items and add them to the list, calling the code above again.

I have implemented something similar, which is an endless pager with loads of hi-res pictures, however, I am not using fragments, so I am not fully aware of how they are removed from the list.

I can see you do not override *isViewFromObject*, perhaps you want to add the following method in your pager adapter:

```
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    View _view = (View) object;
    return view == _view;
}
```

Comment: I have edited my first question to show you how I load TypeFace. I don't think TypeFace loading is the problem. I have tried to use your code (PagerAdapter), but the memory leak problem is still there. Please also find attached, a screen of my DDMS console (byte array > 176 Mb!)

Comment: @Guicara, updated my response you will need to change the way you populate your list, I believe. Also, I might be saying complete nonsense but if none of that works override *saveState()* returning null and test.

Comment: Please see my updated question (edit 2). Thanks! If I am wrong, I'll test your updated answer.

Comment: I think that line "object = null;" doesn't make any sense as you just erase a copy of the reference which is passed to the method

Comment: @Leo true, the end of method scope should take care of cleaning it up. It doesn't make sense to set objects to null in Java.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the [sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java) and first that comes to mind is that no one really calls `destroyItem()`. You should probably do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

With the code you provided, things look fine but there's one method that I suggest you to check it carefully:

```
ViewUtil.setTypeFace(app.getTrebuchet(), vg);
```

Be careful when using custom typeface since it may causes memory leak. You can read these two topic for more details and solution:
[Memory leaks with custom font for set custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901930/memory-leaks-with-custom-font-for-set-custom-font)

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904

Comment: I have edited my first question to show you how I load TypeFace. I don't think TypeFace loading is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem earlier with my app. The solution that worked for me was to have my adapter implement SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter.
https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: I have implemented the SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter but the problem is still there. So I start to think that the problem is on my Day fragment: something must prevent the Garbage Collector to do his job.

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader to populate your ImageViews instead of the default method. This library takes care of the memory, caches the images and much more. Your plroblem possibly lies in

```
mLeft.setImageResource(this.dayUtilPrev.getDrawable());
mCenter.setImageResource(dayUtil.getDrawable());
mRight.setImageResource(this.dayUtilNext.getDrawable());
```

Those funcions, which are called each time a new fragment is called, use whole lot of bitmap decoding functions like

> `at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
>               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
>               at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
>               at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)`

Those will fill your memory in notime if not handled properly

Comment: I am confused, because of this comment from the UIL project page: `NOTE: Use drawable:// only if you really need it! Always consider the native way to load drawables - ImageView.setImageResource(...) instead of using of ImageLoader.` Ref:github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader. I'll try this library and come back here.

Comment: When the library load an image from memory cache (so image already cached = pages already viewed from the ViewPager), the heap size is stable. But, when the app load a new image (new page from the ViewPager), the heap size keeps growing! I don't understand why the garbage collector do not free the memory...

Answer (score 0):

You have added the intent filter MAIN to the Splash activity. It ends,and the next thread that does all the heavy work(MainActivity) has the default priority(0).
Android activity priority can be from 0 to 1000.Along with this I've added android:largeHeap as well to your manifest.

Also you can have two activity's with intent filter MAIN.
Update your manifest like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example" >

    <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="11"
       android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission ...>

    <supports-screens
       android:smallScreens="false"
       android:normalScreens="true"
       android:largeScreens="true"
       android:xlargeScreens="true"
       android:anyDensity="true" />

    <application
       android:name="com.example.MyApplication"
       android:largeHeap="true"
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name">

        <!-- ACTIVITIES -->
        <activity
           android:name="com.example.ui.SplashActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
           android:name="com.example.ui.MainActivity"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait"
           android:label="@string/app_name" 
           android:priority:"900">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- ROBOSPICE SERVICES -->
        <service
           android:name="com.example.network.CalendarSpiceService"
           android:exported="false" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my AndroidManifest file but I don't see notable change (but the code will be always better with that).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for reviving an old post, bu I thought I'd contribute my approch.

I solved it in my app by using

```
tiv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(outFile.getPath()));
```

instead of

```
tiv.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(outFile.getAbsolutePath()));
```

to set the image to my ImageView. My app now regularly cleares heap to ~25-30 MB. With my previous approach my heap grew endlessly. It seems that Bitmapfactory can handle it's memory usage better.

Comment: Thanks. I will try your solution in the next update of my app.